# Qt debugging: viewing vectors?

Tags: qt, debugging, vector, clang

Does anyone have any tips for viewing vectors when debugging from Qt Creator? I've already built the debugger helper, but I can only see the start and end nodes. (I imagine this is probably true for other STL containers as well.)

It's really a drag on debugging time; does anyone know of a fix? Thanks.

Comment: Which debugger?  If you are using `gdb`, have you pointed it to the STL pretty printers? http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Comment: According to the preferences window, I am indeed using /usr/bin/gdb. I downloaded the support tools that you linked, created a .gdbinit file that points to them, but I didn't see any change in my the "locals" window of Creator. I wonder if it knows to look in my user directory for the .gdbinit file...

Comment: Anyone have any further guidance on this? It's getting annoying enough to go back to using arrays instead of vectors. Thanks...

Comment: It must be something wrong with your pretty printer installation, because I can see inside the STL, Qt's types, and Eigen types without a problem.

Comment: Well, that's certainly possible -- I'm not very experienced in the *NIX world. It seemed to go OK, though...are there any log files left behind that I might look at?   Also, I didn't mention I'm using Clang -- do I need to change a setting within Qt's preferences to "pick up" the pretty printers?

Comment: Ahh, I have _no_ experience with Clang.  It could be that, I'll add it as a tag and hopefully someone more experienced can pick up your question.